# Removing contiguous duplicate lines in VIM exception condition without sorting

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I would like to perform the remove contiguous duplicate lines step with exception condition and without sorting in VIM

Example below:

Before Regex

```
a
b
c
d
00
f
b
00
c
e
00
```

After Run Regex

```
a
b
c
d
00
f
00
e
00
```

I want to delete duplicate lines without delete "00" pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim is very powerful editor, however for this problem, I would turn to external utility for an easy solution.

If you have awk available(which is default installed on most linux distributions), you can do this in your vim:

```
:%!awk '/^00$/||\!a[$0]++'
```

Comment: Thanks :)  So, what is mean '/^00$/||\!a[$0]++' ? I know !a[$0]++ is to delete duplicate.

Comment: @이원준      if you know `awk '!a[$0]++'` is removing dups, you should know it is a boolean, if the result is true, the current line will be printed. now I added another boolean `/^00$/`, if the line matches this regex, it will be printed out.  So shortly, the expression is: `lineMatch(/^00$/) OR lineNotDuplicated`

Comment: Goooooood explain : )

Answer (score 2):

With the following, it should work:

```
function! s:HandleLine()
  let line = getline('.')
  if has_key(s:seen, line)
    delete
  else
    let s:seen[line] = 1
  endif
endfunction


command! -range=% -nargs=1 UnsortUniq let s:seen={}<bar><line1>,<line2>v/<args>/call s:HandleLine()
```

Then execute `:%UnsorUniq ^00$`

Answer (score 0):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides (among others) this command:

```
:%DeleteDuplicateLinesIgnoring /00/
```